# Flutter decoded message is too big

Tags: flutter, stomp

I am using [this Flutter stomp client](https://pub.dev/packages/stomp_dart_client) for sending messages.
Small images are working fine, but I'm getting:

```
The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages
```

Here's my code:

```
  client.send(
        destination: '/app/gifts',
        body: json.encode(
        "content": content,
        "sender": senderName,
        "userId": userId,
        "imgData": base64String,
        ),
      );
```

After searching I found that I should increase MessageBufferSize so how can we do that?

I'm using Spring Boot on the server side.